# 550 5.1.1 <user@mail.midomain.com> User doesn't exist: user@mail.midomain.com (in reply to RCPT TO command))

Tags: linux, email, postfix, gentoo, dovecot

this is just killing me I really need fix it, well I'm setting up a Postfix Dovecot Sasl server in Gentoo with a FQDN for my personal domain and till now I can't surpass this

`May 27 21:11:05 mail postfix/lmtp[3857]: 5EF9F41D14B8: to=<user@mail.midomain.com>, orig_to=<user@midomain.com>, relay=mail.midomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=8823, delays=8822/0.13/0.1/0.05, dsn=4.1.1, status=SOFTBOUNCE (host mail.midomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <user@mail.midomain.com> User doesn't exist: user@mail.midomain.com (in reply to RCPT TO command))`

my postconf is on https://dpaste.com/29GUHS4DQ

I know it has to be just one little thing but i have not find it, I check permission on the mailbox there are user:mail on each file on /var/mail/* I did uncomment `user_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%u))` and `recipient_delimiter = +`

I have not set virtual manuelly since only need the local users UNIX Users, what else could be ?

```
postconf -n
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 3.6
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 4
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps =
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 10.8.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix/${mail_version}
smtp_enforce_tls = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/My_CA_Bundle.crt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Can you post a `postconf -n` instead? And if you only need local UNIX users, then why are you uncommenting various LDAP configurations?

Comment: user1686 Thank You for your time in did, I have update the question to put the output of postconf -n, an about uncoment something on ldap options I have not or I'm not sure honestly but I have search in all the files any referenc to ldap and nothig it's uncoment hopefully you can help me thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

It's *Dovecot* who rejects mail, read an error message carefully: `host mail.midomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <user@mail.midomain.com> User doesn't exist: user@mail.midomain.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)`.

Notice also, `to=<user@mail.midomain.com>, orig_to=<user@midomain.com>` in the beginning of the error message. Why it become `user@mail...`? Do you have an alias which maps `user@midomain.com` users to `user@mail.midomain.com`? Was it desired?

Also, there is another problem, which may put your server into various blacklists. You have empty `local_recipient_maps`. So, Postfix will recieve *and queue* the mail for any user within your domain, but if the mail will be further rejected by Dovecot, it will bounce, [generating](https://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html#main_config) a [backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)), which is seen as spam by many. Better leave the default setting which has `unix:passwd.byname` in it, so Postfix will reject such mail early and won't generate backscatter.

Comment: Thank you Nikita, I was thinking on it like it should be the map but I have not figure out how to set it correctly in fact the empty local_recipient_maps I set it to see it helps but not, thank you for advice how i should set the maps to user@mydomain.com goes to user@mail.mydomain.com I try in alias but if i set user@mydomain.com user it do not work well it's worn right could you please tell me how i should do it thank you !